# How to extract a cell value from a Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns, like this:

[image]

I want to search for 12295682 in instrument_token column and extract the related tradingsymbol UBL20JANFUT.

How do I do that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter by condition and by column name:

```
s = df.loc[df['instrument_token'].eq(12295682), 'tradingsymbol']
#alternative
s = df.loc[df['instrument_token'] == 12295682, 'tradingsymbol']
```

And then get first value of `Series`:

```
a = s.iat[0]
a = s.iloc[0]
a = s.tolist()[0]
a = s.to_array()[0]
#general solution if not match condition and select first value failed
a = next(iter(s), 'no match')
```

Another idea is use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) fo index by column `instrument_token`:

```
df = df.set_index('instrument_token')
```

Anf then select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or 
[`DataFrame.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
a = df.loc[12295682, 'tradingsymbol']
a = df.at[12295682, 'tradingsymbol']
```

Comment: Why are the above methods better than simple `df[df['instrument_token'] == 12295682]['tradingsymbol']`?

Comment: @Raj - It return one element Series, so then is necessary select first value

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
list(df.loc[df['instrument_token'] == '12295682', 'tradingsymbol'])[0]

# UBL20JANFUT
```

Answer (score 4):

Filter the df based on the specified value then select the desired column.

```
df.loc[df['instrument_token'] == 12295682]['tradingsymbol']
```

Comment: This returns a length-1 `Series` containing the value, not the value itself.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
df2=df['Trading_symbol'][df['instrument_token']==12295682]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.